# Get value Parameter from onclick() text field in one and the same JSP

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp, servlets

I'm writing on a Web Application (Crowdfunding Platform - Student Project) and my Problem is a JSP page where the user can back a Project. 
I have a form field for the User where he can type in the amount of his donation and after this the same JSP should display the associated rewards. Finally he can submit the action to the Servlet.

```
<input type="text" class="login_spende" maxlength="10" id="spendeBetrag" name="spendeBetrag" value="1 &euro;" onFocus="if(this.value=='1 &euro;') this.value='';" onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value='1 &euro;';">

<input type="button" value="Reward auswählen" onclick="doSomething()">
```

This is the code to get the associated rewards with reference to the donation

```
<%
        List<RewardDAO> rewards = RewardDB.getProjektRewardsByBetrag(spendeBetrag, projektid);
            for (RewardDAO reward : rewards) {
        %>  
        <div class="rewards_spende_box">
            <div>

            </div>
            <div class="rewards_spende" style="background-color:#BBBBBB;" >
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox_spende" name="spendeReward" value="<%= reward.getRewardID() %>" />
            <div class="betrag_spende"><%=reward.getBetrag()%>&euro;</div>
            <div class="rewardtext_projektseite"><%=reward.getBeschreibung()%></div>
            </div>
        </div>  
        <%
            }
        %>
```

The Word "spendeBetrag" is german for "donationValue" ;)

But how is it possible to load the reward list after the user confirmed his donation value because the paramater "spendeBetrag" in `getProjektRewardsByBetrag(spendeBetrag, projektid);` depends on the text field above.

My idea was it to do this with JavaScript, the reward list is on display: none but when the user pushed the button with the donation it should be display: block; but I'm unable to paste the value "spendeBetrag" into the Java code.

Another idea was it to paste this code in an extra Servlet but then I have to load the page twice and this is not what I want.

I hope anyone has a better idea.
Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using AJAX. There you can post data without reloading the whole Page.